# Excel - How to index and match values using header and subheader?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I am presented with financial data that contains a header for various regions, and a sub-header for different years under each region, as per Table 1 below.

I am trying to write a formula in cells B4 to B6 in Table 2 that would match the location in cell B1 and the year in cell B2 to the header and sub-header in Table 1 and index for the values.

I tried the standard index and match combination, but it requires one row and one column reference. Here I think I would be dealing with 1 row reference (the financial metrics) and two columns references (the location and year).

[image]

Edit: Sorry, I tried to post my data in markdown format, but for some reason its not posting correctly, despite the previewing having no issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SUMIFS with INDEX/MATCH:

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX(Sheet1!B:I,MATCH(A4,Sheet1!A:A,0),0),Sheet1!$B$1:$I$1,$B$1,Sheet1!$B$2:$I$2,$B$2)
```

The `INDEX(Sheet1!B:I,MATCH(A4,Sheet1!A:A,0),0)` returns the correct row to the SUMIFS, which then sums the values where the two criteria match.  Because they are unique combinations it will only return the sum of one value which is the value.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use a SUMIFS formula.

```
Cell B13 formula: =SUMIFS($B3:$F3,$B$1:$F$1,B$10,$B$2:$F$2,B$11)
```

Drag it across and down.

[image]